# How to see if an array has a value, and return true if it does. - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

*Both arrays contain the string 'hello', but only the first logs true. Why?*

```js
function containsHello(array){
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(array[i] === 'hello'){
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }
}

console.log(containsHello(['hello', 'no', 'yes'])); // logs true
console.log(containsHello(['no', 'hello', 'yes'])); // logs false
```

Comment: Put a `console.log` in the loop. How many times does it print? How many times do you expect it to print?

Comment: Try == instead of ===, see what happens.

Answer (score 2):

In your code where you are returning `false`, you are returning too soon (before checking all elements)

you should return false after the loop is finished

```
function containsHello(array){
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(array[i] === 'hello'){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, if the element is NOT `'hello'`, it immediately returns false but hasn't got a chance to check any potentially preceding elements. Remember if a function reaches a return statement it (prematurely) ends. Just a small logic mistake.

Also...

`includes` is a method. I don't even need to explain.

```js
var someList = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
console.log(someList.includes('c')) // --> true
```

Comment: I didn't know how to use .includes() until i posted this, so thank you for that explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Thats because for the second the hello is at index position 1.
While iterating over the array, it sees the 'no' value first and just returns.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is that it will always return on the first item, and never check the other values. Remove the `else` block, and return `false` after the loop.

Alternatively, just use [`array.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).

Answer (score 0):

You are returning false if the first element is not equal to 'hello'
Instead try this function

```
function containsHello(array){
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(array[i] === 'hello'){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a logical error in your function. It returns false if the first element is not `'hello`'. However, this does not make sense, as `'hello'` could still be contained in the other values. This can be fixed by returning false only after checking all of the values.

```js
function containsHello(array){
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(array[i] === 'hello'){
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(containsHello(['hello', 'no', 'yes']));
console.log(containsHello(['no', 'hello', 'yes']));
console.log(containsHello(['no','yes','also no']));
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be better this:

```
function containsHello(array){
  return array.indexOf('hello') !== -1; 
}
```

Comment: Index checks for potentially non-existent elements are ugly when `Array.includes` exists.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) if you want to skip the for loop.

```
function containsHello(array){
  if(array.includes("Hello")) {
     return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

or you could do the following if you want to search for different words

```
function containsWord(word, array){
      if(array.includes(word)) {
         return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }
```

Comment: At that point, it's just a wrapper for `includes`.

Comment: I agree, I just gave it to him in a function because his initial post had a function. Otherwise a console.log(array.contains('x')); works perfectly fine.

Ah, I see you posted a solution with .includes also.

Comment: I like this explanation as well, others have mentioned .includes() but i just wanted to see it as a function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the .includes() function for this purpose like this:

```
[].includes('value')
```

Then:

```
console.log(['no','hello','yes'].includes('hello')); //logs true
console.log(['hello','no','yes'].includes('hello')); //logs true
```

Comment: You don't really explain the initial problem, which is pretty important.

Comment: I know, I just tried to answer the initial question "How to see if an array has a value and return true if it does javascript".  I will consider it for next time, thanks for your remark.